# How to use curl with a website that shows dialog asking for authentication

Tags: http, curl

```
curl http://example.com
```

returns HTTP 401 error,

when I open http://example.com in the browser it shows :

[image]

how to enter the username and password through `curl`

**Note:**

I have tried this one based on one of the answers and I get the same message :

```
curl --user myuser:123456 http://example.com
401 Unauthorized
```

**The Solution**

I've just added "--ntlm" and it works !

```
curl --user myuser:123456 http://example.com --ntlm
```

I'll choose the nearest answer...

Comment: @MarcB as a command line ( linux )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work , I put the message in the question

Comment: @BugKiller Yeah, the authentication protocol sometimes matters. I assumed it was just basic auth.